# How to make JSON response data dynamic?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code which retrieves data with a JSON request:

```
// Replace home page template wildcards with data from database (JSON)
$.getJSON("mvc/models/home.php?action=getpagecontent&&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {

// Set markup identifiers
var identifiers = new Array(); 
identifiers[0] = "introheader1";      
identifiers[1] = "introtext1";      

// Replace markup on page
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {  
    if (data[x].introheader1 != undefined){
      $(".introheader1").replaceWith(data[x].introheader1);
    }
    if (data[x].introtext1 != undefined){
      $(".introtext1").replaceWith(data[x].introtext1);
    }
  }  
});
```

This works fine, but is a pain if there a lot of elements returned. So instead of this for every element:

```
    if (data[x].introheader1 != undefined){
      $(".introheader1").replaceWith(data[x].introheader1);
    }
```

I want to make it dynamic by replacing the hard coded values with the values from the identifiers array, like this, so I only have to have one and can loop through:

```
    if (data[x].identifiers[0] != undefined){
        $("." + identifiers[0]).replaceWith(data[x].identifiers[0]);
    }
```

But it gives an error at the "data[x]." replacements. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: What's with the `&&` in the url? I think 1 `&` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `for` to this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {  
  for(var prop in data[x]){
     $("."+prop).replaceWith(data[x][prop]);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers